# How do you convert 3 bytes into a 24 bit number in C#?

Tags: c#

I have an array of bytes that I read from a header section of a message. These bytes contain the length of the message. There never are more than 3 bytes and they are ordered from LSB to MSB. So in the example below, 39 is the LSB and 2 is the MSB.

```
var data = new byte[] { 39, 213, 2 };
```

In the example above how can I take those bytes and convert to a number (int,short,etc)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice for converting 24bit, little endian, two's complement values to ints in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322788/best-practice-for-converting-24bit-little-endian-twos-complement-values-to-int)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var num = data[0] + (data[1] << 8) + (data[2] << 16);
```

Comment: I believe an important note here is that this code will only work with an unsigned integer. This is a valid response since the bytes contain the length (which we can assume is an unsigned int).

Comment: @Crimson - Wait... You mean messages don't usually have negative lengths? :)

Comment: Very true :-). For signed integers, as LukeH suggests you can refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322788/best-practice-for-converting-24bit-little-endian-twos-complement-values-to-int

Answer (score 8):

Use methods like [BitConverter.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32.aspx), but realize that you'll need 4 bytes for 32 bit quantities.

```
var data = new byte[] {39, 213, 2, 0};
int integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
```

There are also [other methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzx26z14.aspx) to convert to and from other types like [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle.aspx) and [Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.todouble.aspx).

Comment: Oops, forgot about that. They really have everything don't they?

Comment: That will crash in the given example, because it needs four bytes

Comment: It was a race against the fastest guns in the west around here ;). I updated it. I like using BitConverter vs hardcoding the conversion to make it more readable and clear what the code is doing.

Comment: @Jeff - The only annoying part about this would be if they receive a 3 byte array from an external API.

Comment: Be aware that the endian-ness used by `BitConverter` is platform-dependent whereas the OP's data is always little-endian. If you want this to work correctly on all platforms then you'll need to check the `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` property and reverse your `data` array if necessary.

Comment: The hidden endian-ness of BitConverter is a serious disadvantage over the shifting and adding, to my mind - at least it's explicit at the point of conversion what you're doing.  But I still use BitConverter all the time, so who am I to complain...

Comment: The question specifically asks for 24 bit, not 32 bit. BitConverter wont work in this scenario.

Answer (score 5):

Use the Left-shift operator and the or operator:

```
int d = (data[2] << 16) | (data[1] << 8) | data[0]
```

Obviously, you could do all sorts of things here, like using a loop etc :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
data[0] + 256*data[1] + 256*256*data[2]
```

Your compiler should optimize that to the 'right' bit twiddling operations.

Answer (score -1):

BitConverter handles the endianness for you which is why it's the way to go.

While you need 4 bytes, do

```
BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[1] { 0 }.Concat(yourThreeByteArray).ToArray());
```