# readData for 24-bit FLAC and WAV files

Tags: c#, audio, io, fmod

I used readData successfully to read 16-bit audio files and generate peak files for wave form display. However, I'm having some trouble interpreting PCM values for 24-bit FLAC and WAV files.

First, what is the block size for 24-bit?

16-bit signed values ranges from -32768 to +32768 and 24-bit ranges from -8388607 to +8388607.

I used 4096 bytes block size for 16-bit files (65536 / 16 = 4096). It works fine for detecting peaks.

If I do the same calculation with 24-bit, 16777215 / 24 = 699050.625 bytes. Am I mistaken? I guess I have to use 32-bit variables to store the 24-bit values. But what block size should I use when reading the file? 699051? How do I adjust the conversion to float arrays?

Here is the full C# code I'm using to generate peak files for 16-bit PCM data. I've left the 24-bit code empty on purpose since it doesn't work. Some code references my own FMOD wrapper but it should be simple to understand.

```
 // Declare variables
            FMOD.RESULT result = FMOD.RESULT.OK;
            FileStream fileStream = null;
            BinaryWriter binaryWriter = null;
            GZipStream gzipStream = null;
            bool generatePeakFile = false;
            int CHUNKSIZE = 0;
            uint length = 0;
            uint read = 0;
            uint bytesread = 0;
            Int16[] left16BitArray = null;
            Int16[] right16BitArray = null;
            Int32[] left32BitArray = null;
            Int32[] right32BitArray = null;
            float[] floatLeft = null;
            float[] floatRight = null;
            byte[] buffer = null;
            IntPtr data = new IntPtr(); // initialized properly later
            WaveDataMinMax minMax = null;

            try
            {
                // Set current file directory
                m_peakFileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\Peak Files\\";

                // Get file name from argument
                string fileName = (string)e.Argument;

                // Create sound system with NOSOUND
                MPfm.Sound.System soundSystem = new MPfm.Sound.System(FMOD.OUTPUTTYPE.NOSOUND, string.Empty);

                // Create sound
                MPfm.Sound.Sound sound = soundSystem.CreateSound(fileName, false);

                // Get sound format; specifically bits per sample (changes the calculations later)
                SoundFormat soundFormat = sound.GetSoundFormat();

                // Get the length of the file in PCM bytes               
                sound.BaseSound.getLength(ref length, FMOD.TIMEUNIT.PCMBYTES);

                // Check if the folder for peak files exists
                if (!Directory.Exists(PeakFileDirectory))
                {
                    // Create directory
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(PeakFileDirectory);
                }

                // Generate the file name for the peak file by using the full path without special characters
                string peakFilePath = PeakFileDirectory + fileName.Replace(@"\", "_").Replace(":", "_").Replace(".", "_") + ".mpfmPeak";

                // Check if peak file exists                
                if(!File.Exists(peakFilePath))
                {
                    // Set flag
                    generatePeakFile = true;

                    // Create peak file
                    fileStream = new FileStream(peakFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                    binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);
                    gzipStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Compress);                   
                }

                // Check the bits per sample to determine what chunk size to get                
                if (soundFormat.BitsPerSample == 16)
                {
                    // 4096 bytes for 16-bit PCM data
                    CHUNKSIZE = 4096;
                }
                else if (soundFormat.BitsPerSample == 24)
                {
                    // 699050.625 bytes for 24-bit PCM data (???)   
                    CHUNKSIZE = 699051;
                }

                // Create buffer
                data = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(CHUNKSIZE);
                buffer = new byte[CHUNKSIZE];

                // Loop through file using chunk size
                do
                {
                    // Check for cancel
                    if (m_workerWaveForm.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Check the bits per sample
                    if (soundFormat.BitsPerSample == 16)
                    {
                        // Read data chunk (4096 bytes for 16-bit PCM data)
                        result = sound.BaseSound.readData(data, (uint)CHUNKSIZE, ref read);
                        Marshal.Copy(data, buffer, 0, CHUNKSIZE);
                        bytesread += read;

                        // Is freehglobal needed? it crashes after one use.
                        //Marshal.FreeHGlobal(data);

                        // Convert the byte (8-bit) arrays into a short (16-bit) arrays (signed values)
                        left16BitArray = new Int16[buffer.Length / 4];
                        right16BitArray = new Int16[buffer.Length / 4];

                        // Loop through byte (8-bit) array buffer; increment by 4 (i.e. 4 times more data in 16-bit than 8-bit)
                        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i = i + 4)
                        {
                            // Convert values to 16-bit
                            left16BitArray[i / 4] = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, i);
                            right16BitArray[i / 4] = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, i + 2); // alternate between left and right channel
                        }

                        // Convert the short arrays to float arrays (signed values)
                        // This will convert the -32768 to 32768 value range to -1 to 1 (useful for wave display) 
                        floatLeft = new float[left16BitArray.Length];
                        floatRight = new float[left16BitArray.Length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < left16BitArray.Length; i++)
                        {
                            // 16-bit data for unsigned values range from 0 to 65536.
                            floatLeft[i] = left16BitArray[i] / 65536.0f;
                            floatRight[i] = right16BitArray[i] / 65536.0f;                            
                        }
                    }
                    else if (soundFormat.BitsPerSample == 24)
                    {
                       // (non-working code removed)

                        // (I have no idea if this works) Convert the short arrays to float arrays (signed values)
                        // This will convert the -8388608 to 8388608value range to -1 to 1 (useful for wave display) 
                        floatLeft = new float[left32BitArray.Length];
                        floatRight = new float[left32BitArray.Length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < left32BitArray.Length; i++)
                        {
                            // 16-bit data for unsigned values range from 0 to 16777215.
                            floatLeft[i] = left32BitArray[i] / 16777215.0f;
                            floatRight[i] = right32BitArray[i] / 16777215.0f;                            
                        }
                    }

                    // Calculate min/max
                    minMax = AudioTools.GetMinMaxFromWaveData(floatLeft, floatRight, false);
                    WaveDataHistory.Add(minMax);

                    // Report progress
                    m_bytesRead = bytesread;
                    m_totalBytes = length;
                    m_percentageDone = ((float)bytesread / (float)length) * 100;

                    // Write peak information to hard disk
                    if (generatePeakFile)
                    {
                        // Write peak information
                        binaryWriter.Write((double)minMax.leftMin);
                        binaryWriter.Write((double)minMax.leftMax);
                        binaryWriter.Write((double)minMax.rightMin);
                        binaryWriter.Write((double)minMax.rightMax);
                        binaryWriter.Write((double)minMax.mixMin);
                        binaryWriter.Write((double)minMax.mixMax);
                    }                  
                }
                while (result == FMOD.RESULT.OK && read == CHUNKSIZE);

                // Release sound from memory
                sound.Release();

                // Close sound system and release from memory
                soundSystem.Close();
                soundSystem.Release();

                // Set nulls for garbage collection               
                sound = null;
                soundSystem = null;
                left16BitArray = null;
                right16BitArray = null;
                left32BitArray = null;
                right32BitArray = null;
                floatLeft = null;
                floatRight = null;                
                buffer = null;
                minMax = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Did we have to generate a peak file?
                if (generatePeakFile)
                {
                    // Close writer and stream
                    gzipStream.Close();
                    binaryWriter.Close();                   
                    fileStream.Close();

                    // Set nulls
                    gzipStream = null;
                    binaryWriter = null;
                    fileStream = null;
                }
            }

            // Call garbage collector
            GC.Collect();
```

Here is the method that extracts the min/max values from float arrays:

```
/// <summary>
/// This method takes the left channel and right channel wave raw data and analyses it to get
/// the maximum and minimum values in the float structure. It returns a data structure named
/// WaveDataMinMax (see class description for more information). Negative values can be converted to
/// positive values before min and max comparaison. Set this parameter to true for output meters and
/// false for wave form display controls.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="waveDataLeft">Raw wave data (left channel)</param>
/// <param name="waveDataRight">Raw wave data (right channel)</param>
/// <param name="convertNegativeToPositive">Convert negative values to positive values (ex: true when used for output meters, 
/// false when used with wave form display controls (since the negative value is used to draw the bottom end of the waveform).<</param>
/// <returns>WaveDataMinMax data structure</returns>
public static WaveDataMinMax GetMinMaxFromWaveData(float[] waveDataLeft, float[] waveDataRight, bool convertNegativeToPositive)
{
    // Create default data
    WaveDataMinMax data = new WaveDataMinMax();

    // Loop through values to get min/max
    for (int i = 0; i < waveDataLeft.Length; i++)
    {
        // Set values to compare
        float left = waveDataLeft[i];
        float right = waveDataRight[i];

        // Do we have to convert values before comparaison?
        if (convertNegativeToPositive)
        {
            // Compare values, if negative then remove negative sign
            if (left < 0)
            {
                left = -left;
            }
            if (right < 0)
            {
                right = -right;
            }
        }

        // Calculate min/max for left channel
        if (left < data.leftMin)
        {
            data.leftMin = left;
        }
        if (left > data.leftMax)
        {
            data.leftMax = left;
        }

        // Calculate min/max for right channel
        if (right < data.rightMin)
        {
            data.rightMin = right;
        }
        if (right > data.rightMax)
        {
            data.rightMax = right;
        }

        // Calculate min/max mixing both channels
        if (left < data.mixMin)
        {
            data.mixMin = left;
        }
        if (right < data.mixMin)
        {
            data.mixMin = right;
        }
        if (left > data.mixMax)
        {
            data.mixMax = left;
        }
        if (right > data.mixMax)
        {
            data.mixMax = right;
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Can anybody give me a hint on what to do? I hope my code isn't too bad and be can used as an example for 16-bit files. Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:**

Here is the 3x8-bit to 24-bit using a 32-bit variable conversion code:

```
                left32BitArray = new Int32[buffer.Length / 6];
                right32BitArray = new Int32[buffer.Length / 6];
                for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i = i + 6)
                {
                        // Create smaller array in order to add the 4th 8-bit value
                        byte[] byteArrayLeft = new byte[4] {buffer[i], buffer[i + 1], buffer[i + 2], 0 };
                        byte[] byteArrayRight = new byte[4] { buffer[i + 3], buffer[i + 4], buffer[i + 5], 0 };

                        // Convert values to 32-bit variables
                        left32BitArray[i / 6] = BitConverter.ToInt32(byteArrayLeft, 0);
                        right32BitArray[i / 6] = BitConverter.ToInt32(byteArrayRight, 0);
                }
```

Comment: Why guessing? Just find out the format of wav file for 24-bit data and it's done.

Comment: What am I guessing exactly? I already know its format using GetSoundFormat, which returns me the frequency, bitrate, bits per sample, etc. Thus I already know it's a 24-bit WAV or FLAC file. I know my 16-bit code assumes the file is using 44100kHz sample rate. I'm already ignoring files with lower frequency/bits per sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

24 bit audio files have a block align of 3 * number of channels. Why not go for 100ms of audio:

```
int blockSize = 3 * channels * (sampleRate / 10);
```

This will work fine for 24 bit WAV. Whether or not your FLAC reader lets you read out to that granularity depends on its internal implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would be that same formula for 16-bit files? I'm going to try this tonight. I'll go for 10ms of data instead, so I'm guessing I have to divide the sampleRate by 100. I'll mark your answer if it works.

Comment: change the 3 to a 2 (3 = 24/8; 2 = 16/8).

Comment: I took a little break for a few days on this problem, I'm sorry for the delay. However, you put me on the right track to understand how the PCM data is stored. My actual comments for the BitConverter part are wrong. I guess I got it working by chance, but it's now clear what I have to do. I have to store the 24-bit values into 32-bit variables (this article helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345553/how-do-you-convert-3-bytes-into-a-24-bit-number-in-c). I'm going to mark your answer as soon as I get it working. Thanks for your second answer!

Comment: It seems to be working, except for the values coming out from the FMOD readData. The data seems to be around 0 or 16777215, which draws a flat waveform. When I look at the data before converting it to 24-bit, it's mostly zeros and 255's. I'm going to post my updated code when I find out what the problem is. Thanks again!